# how to save URL output into a file in PowerShell

Tags: php, powershell

i am a beginner all around PowerShell, and my main difficult is that 
i have the following script and i would like to create a log file from the output of the URL. for now the script is working but i don't know how can i save the browser output to a file. i will need to write the output into new file only in case the file is not created. i try the |Out-File method but nothing happens.

my script:

```
start "http://myurl"
Start-Sleep -s 5
get-process iexplore | stop-process
get-process powershell | stop-process
```

this is my php code:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matant
 * Date: 11/17/2015
 * Time: 1:46 PM
 */
define ('mysql_host','host');
define ('mysql_user','user');
define ('mysql_password','password');
define ('myDB','DBname');


$dblink= mysqli_connect(mysql_host, mysql_user, mysql_password,myDB);


if (!$dblink)
{
    $message = sprintf(
        "Could not connect to local database: %s",
        mysql_error()
    );
    trigger_error($message);
    echo $message;
    return;
}
else{
    echo "connection success"."<br/>";
}
$c_date = date("Y-m-d");
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jerusalem');
$c_time = date("h:i:sa");
$query = "UPDATE event SET event_status = '0' WHERE event.event_date < '$c_date' OR '$c_time' >  event.start_time";
$res = mysqli_query($dblink,$query) or die (mysqli_error($dblink));
if(!$res){
    echo $c_time.":failed to update event!"."<br/>";
}
else{
    echo $c_time."  :event updated successfully";
}
$dblink ->close();
?>
```

for example if the script run successfully i get the message:

```
 connection success
04:39:36pm :event updated successfully
```

which this message i would like to be saved into a file.

Comment: What do you mean with 'browser output'? What information do you want to save? Can you give an example of the output you want in the text file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Invoke-WebRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx)

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.bbc.co.uk" | select -ExpandProperty Content |` Out-File test.txt

Comment: i get this error when i replace all my script with your answer: "The term 'Invoke-WebRequest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,..."

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest was only added in PowerShell 3.0 - looks like you're still running V2 so won't be able to use this function.

Comment: thanks i try it in windows server 2012 and its working thank you.

Comment: but my output into the file is : "connection success<br/>04:56:22pm  :event updated successfully" there is a way to fit it to the browser?

Comment: Do you want to see the message in both a web browser, and in the log file?